# Adding Google Analytics onclick event tracker to Wordpress Social Login Widget elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, authentication, google-analytics

The WSL version we are currently using is 2.3.0.

I want to add a google analytics onclick event tracker to the my social widget elements so that we can analyze the number of people are clicking these sign up methods. Currently, the modal that pops up renders on page load in footer.php. In a separate JS file,I tried to target the Facebook widget, for example, by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tbf-modal-join a.wp-social-login-provider.wp-social-login-provider-facebook").attr('onlick', 'ga('send', 'event', 'Navigation', 'WSL-Facebook');
    })
})
```

This however, didn't work for me (as well as numerous other variations of classes, attributes, e.g. 'setAttribute' instead of attr).

Could anyone please suggest how this could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wp-social-login-provider-facebook').on('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Navigation', 'WSL-Facebook');
  });
});
```

Basically, instead of trying to add the event via an attribute value to the `onclick` attribute, just add the click handler directly via jQuery.

Comment: Hey Philip.

Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately your suggestion didn't trigger an event :/

Looks like it should work too considering the article, http://www.outlier.com/blog/google-event-tracking-jquery#.VqfgxlMrKDU does pretty much the same method.

Comment: Just wondering, how are you determining that the event did not trigger? Are you checking real-time, or GA Debugger, or Network tab?

Comment: I'm checking real-time events.   I've just put another 20 or so hardcoded via Wordpress and it works for our /pricing page.

Comment: None of the jQuery seems to work.  I just tried doing:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;
 $('#gaPricingCheckout').click(function() {
  ga('send', 'event',  'Navigation', 'PricingPage', pathName);
 });
});

and it didn't work either... :/

Comment: Well, if your jQuery code isn't running, that's a different problem and should be debugged separately. Once you get it running the above code will work (assuming the `.wp-social-login-provider-facebook` element is in the DOM and visible).

Comment: Sorry let me just clarify.  None of the jQuery related to the Google Analytics tracker is working.  

The modal that "houses" the WSL widgets is closed via jQuery:  $(document).on('click', '#modal-x-close', function(e) {
 $(this).parent().addClass('displayNone');
 $(this).parent().parent().addClass('displayNone');
 e.preventDefault();
})

so I didn't mean that NONE of the jQuery worked on our page.  My bad for being unclear.

Comment: @IvanRL you need to do a little debugging on your own. Are you using the browser's debug tools? Are there errors being logged to the console? If you don't know, then you should look into that, as learning how to debug your code in the browser's developers tools is an invaluable skill that you will never regret learning.

Comment: Nevermind it works!  I literally re-wrote what you had written originall posted @PhilipWalton in VIM instead of copy and pasting it.

Comment: Great! I still recommend familiarizing yourself with the developer tools. Also, if this answer helped you, you should upvote it and mark it as accepted so others can benefit.